# How do i set a Productcode as Detection Method via New-CMDetectionClauseWindowsInstaller

Tags: powershell, sccm

I have a PowerShell Script that creates Apps with Deployment type... 
I am able to create a DetectionMethod for a Registry Key using New-CMDetectionClauseRegistryKeyValue

But what I want is to have two DetectionMethods. One is the registry key and the other is the ProductCode.

So I do as follows:

```
$clause1 = New-CMDetectionClauseRegistryKeyValue -Hive LocalMachine -KeyName "pathstuff" -Is64Bit -ValueName "aValue" -PropertyType String -ExpressionOperator IsEquals -ExpectedValue $aVar -Value
$clause2 = New-CMDetectionClauseWindowsInstaller -ProductCode $ProductCode
```

But I get an error for the second clause:

> The parameter set cannot be resolved with the specified named
>   parameters

I believe afterwards that my line has to be as follows:

```
Add-CMScriptDeploymentType -ApplicationName $AppName -DeploymentTypeName $DepTypeName -ContentLocation $DepContentLocation -InstallCommand $DepInstallCommand `
            -UninstallCommand $DepUninstallCommand -AddDetectionClause $clause1,$clause2 -EstimatedRuntimeMins $DepMinRuntime -MaximumRuntimeMins $DepMaxRuntime `
            -LogonRequirementType WhetherOrNotUserLoggedOn -UserInteractionMode Hidden -InstallationBehaviorType InstallForSystem -AddRequirement $oDTRule
```

But I get the error

> The argument cannot be bound to the AddDetectionClause parameter
>   because it is NULL.

Because clause 2 does not work...

I found out that it seems to work if you do it like this:

```
$clause1 = New-CMDetectionClauseWindowsInstaller -ProductCode $guid [Value -ExpressionOperator IsEquals -ExpectedValue "1.1.1.1" # Do a version check
```

But this would be the second Radiobutton in SCCM and I want the first.

I just don't know what I am missing. There is no documentation on this one... and Google doesn't give me not much...

Any help would be appreciated.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was bugging me now for several Weeks and in the end it is just a case of RTFM.
So on the Microsoft Docs [Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/configurationmanager/new-cmdetectionclausewindowsinstaller?view=sccm-ps) of this command is the Answer I just wasn't able to read it.

```
$clause2 = New-CMDetectionClauseWindowsInstaller -ProductCode $ProductCode -Existence
```

You just need to put -Existence at the end and it works.

I was so focused about the fact that there were no examples that i did not read the complete Syntax Description.